# [ROS2] using dynamic parameters in Python

Tags: ros, ros2, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use dynamic parameters in my ROS2 code. I defined a callback function, if a parameter is changed with following line:

```
self.add_on_set_parameters_callback(self.cb_params)
```

I wrote a little example to test it:

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy.exceptions import ParameterNotDeclaredException

class MinimalParam(Node):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__('minimal_param_node')
    timer_period = 2  # seconds
    self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
    self.declare_parameter("name", "world")

    self.add_on_set_parameters_callback(self.cb_params)
    self.name = self.get_parameter("name").get_parameter_value().string_value

def cb_params(self, data):

    self.get_logger().warn("parameter changed...")
    self.successful = True
    self.name = self.get_parameter("name").get_parameter_value().string_value
    return self


def timer_callback(self):

    self.get_logger().info('Hello %s!' % self.name)

def main():
    rclpy.init()
    node = MinimalParam()
    rclpy.spin(node)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I changed the parameter over the ros2 command in a terminal with:

```
ros2 param set /minimal_param_node name "earth"
```

With the log message I can see that the callback is working, but the parameter is not changed the first time. When I call the ros2 command again, the parameter changed to the value set before.

FYI:
The line:

```
self.successful = True
return self
```

is needed, because without them the code is crashing with an Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'successful'
```

I'm working with Foxy on Ubuntu 20.04 . Unfortunately I could not find any documentation/tutorial on this. What did i wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355508/%5Bros2%5D-using-dynamic-parameters-in-python/) by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 219 on 2020-06-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

change you callback function

```
   from rcl_interfaces.msg import SetParametersResult
   from rclpy.parameter import Parameter
   ...
   def cb_params(self, data):
        for parameter in data:
        if parameter.name == "name":
            if parameter.type_ == Parameter.Type.STRING:
                self.name = parameter.value
    self.get_logger().warn("parameter changed... {}".format(self.name))
    return SetParametersResult(successful=True)
```

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.ros.org/users/50386/ahcorde/) with karma: 421 on 2020-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on 2020-06-22**:
Thats it!
Thanks